# unfortunately "name application" has stopped android eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/engadget"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Engadget" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

bestblog.java

```
package com.example.bestblog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class bestblog extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addListemerOnButton();
}

private void addListemerOnButton() {

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.engadget);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent browserIntent = 
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,      Uri.parse("http://www.engadget.com"));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
        }


    });

}
}
```

If I use a Android Simulator to run my application, I get a error message.
I don't know how to fix it, I get this error message "unfortunately "name application" has stopped".

Comment: Post your logcat output.

Comment: post the error 'LogCat'.

Comment: It is a link of a Error Logcat screen shot. http://prntscr.com/31f8u1

Answer (score 1):

Change this line of your layout xml...

```
     tools:context=".MainActivity"
```

to...

```
    tools:context=".bestblog"
```

Comment: This is my log cast.
I save it in a website because it's very long.
http://justpaste.it/erj4

Comment: I have seen your LogCat...Now, do what I'm saying.

Comment: I change this. But this don't work.

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".bestblog" >

Comment: clean your project then run it.